# Is there a way to have a bot respond to a one of three messages, each with their own responses to a set of messages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have an excuse generator and decided to transfer it over to a bot. From what I have seen the command is a branching path. It asks, you respond, and then it asks again based on your previous answer.

The problem is the `QuestionOneOne = int(input())`, `QuestionOneTwo = int(input())`, and `QuestionOneThree = int(input())`. I understand what they do but not how to make it work on Discord where the questions are asked like how those 3 lines look for the response in the command prompt.

**TL;DR: `int(input())` makes the bot look for response in command prompt. I don't know how to make it look in chat.**

Here's the code that is the issue. The bit after it would work ok if this part is fixed.

```py
@client.command()
async def yote(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Welcome to the EXCUSE GENERATOR")
  await ctx.send("This is a generator that creates a random EXCUSE for you")
  await ctx.send("What do you need an excuse for?")
  await ctx.send("1: I forgot")
  await ctx.send("2: I lost")
  await ctx.send("3: I didn't do")
  QuestionOne = int(input())
  if QuestionOne == 1:
    await ctx.send("What did you forget?")
    await ctx.send("1: Homework")
    await ctx.send("2: An object")
    await ctx.send("3: A concept")
    QuestionOneOne = int(input())
  elif QuestionOne == 2:
    await ctx.send("What did you lose?")
    await ctx.send("1: Something expensive")
    await ctx.send("2: Something cheap")
    await ctx.send("3: Someone")
    QuestionOneTwo = int(input())
  elif QuestionOne == 3:
    await ctx.send("What didn't you do?")
    await ctx.send("1: Your homework")
    await ctx.send("2: An errand")
    await ctx.send("3: Something important")
    QuestionOneThree = int(input())
    Thing = str(input())
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`Client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) / [`Bot.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for) method and specify `"message"` for the `event`.
You'll want to add a check as well, e.g. for the channel or author, integer input, etc.